# Angular - Create JSON object to store data associated with each route

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-router, stringtemplate

I want to create a JSON object which holds help text for each route in the Angular 6 app.

```
let helpRoutes = {
 'wizard/{some_id}/step1': 'This is help content for step 1',
 'wizard/{some_id}/step2': 'This is help content for step 2',
 'user/details/{some_id}/tab1': 'This is help content for user details with activated tab 1'
 'user/details/{some_id}/tab2': 'This is help content for user details with activated tab 2'
}
```

So if I want to access help for step 1 for any screen_id, I should get it with:

```
helpRoutes['wizard-fa/123456/step4'];
```

Above code is obviously incorrect and giving me 'undefined' and that is why I asked this question.

Can we achieve what I wanted to do using JSON's key value pair?

If yes, then how. If no, what are the alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you having a unique component for each route?

Comment: Yes. For example, if user hit 'wizard/16854/step1', there will be a unique component which is step1. Same would be the case for 'wizard/16854/step2' and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your routes, you can add static data

```
{ path: 'my-route', component: MyComponent, data: {
  help: 'This is help content for component'
}}
```

And you can use it with an instance of `ActivatedRoute`

```
constructor(
  route: ActivatedRoute
) {
  console.log(route.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
let helpRoutes = {
 'wizard/{screen_id}/step1': 'This is help content for step 1',
 'wizard/{screen_id}/step2': 'This is help content for step 2'
}
```

you can write it as

```
let helpRoutes = {
 'step1': 'This is help content for step 1',
 'step2': 'This is help content for step 2'
}
```

Extract the last word using **/** seperator and get the data from json. Like if route is
`wizard/1234/step1`, get the last word `step1` and then `help[step1]`.

This can be one approach.

Comment: Can't do that. I have different types of routes which can include something like 'user/details/{some_id}/tab1'. Please see the update answer.

Comment: If you don't have URL of this type `some/url/step1` and `another/url/step1`. Then this method will still work. You need to get data as help[step1] and help[tab1] inside the respective components. So are the endings unique or they can clash?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can achieve it by assigning the screen id before calling the helproute object.If you want screen_id to be dynamic then you must have to assing the value to the object first.See the example,

```
   let helpRoutes = {};
    for(let screen_id=0;screen_id<10;screen_id++){
        helpRoutes[`wizard/${screen_id}/step1`] =`This is help content for step ${screen_id}`;
    }
```

After assigning helproutes value you can then get the value.

```
helpRoutes['wizard/2/step1']
```

Comment: I do not have a specific numbers of screen_id. It can be anything. I have updated my answer. I want to put a placeholder for 'some_id'. Thanks.

Comment: When referencing an object the value must be present for getting that.So when you have dynamic routes which will have dynamic help value, You can use a global shared service for this. You will store the values then on every init of the route components so that you can use the help values over the whole portal.

Comment: Instead of route-based help, how about I place the help content in each corresponding component. Would that be a good practice?

Comment: yes it will be.Because nothing is predefined and centrally managed here in your case.You can use this inside your component.